# Serializing data from two URLs in the same object efficiently

Tags: java, optimization, parsing, json, serialization

*This is a follow-up to: [Serializing JSON data coming from two URLs in the same object](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/59844/serializing-json-data-coming-from-two-urls-in-the-same-object)*

I have two URLs (`urlA` and `urlB`) and they both give me a JSON response back in the same JSON format. Below is my JSON string which I am getting back by calling from `urlA`. I have shortened it down by having only three `reportRecords` for understanding purposes. In general, it might have more than ~500 `reportRecords`.

```
{
   "aggRecords": {
      "reportRecords": [
         {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 12,
            "avg": 0.3699187,
            "count": 246,
            "sumSq": 571,
            "stddev": 1.4779372,
            "median": 0,
            "percentileMap": {
               "95": 4
            },
            "metricName": "TransactionDuration",
            "dimensions": {
               "env": "dev",
               "pool": "titan",
               "Name": "PostProcessing",
               "Type": "PostProcessing"
            },
            "value": 91
         },
         {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 23,
            "avg": 2.3991289E-4,
            "count": 1463031,
            "sumSq": 3071,
            "stddev": 0.045814946,
            "median": 0,
            "percentileMap": {
               "95": 0
            },
            "metricName": "TransactionDuration",
            "dimensions": {
               "env": "dev",
               "pool": "titan",
               "Name": "ResourceContext",
               "Type": "ResourceContext"
            },
            "value": 351
         },
         {
            "min": 0,
            "max": 1209,
            "avg": 1.9203402,
            "count": 7344636,
            "sumSq": 71832774,
            "stddev": 2.4683187,
            "median": 2,
            "percentileMap": {
               "95": 4
            },
            "metricName": "TransactionDuration",
            "dimensions": {
               "env": "dev",
               "pool": "titan",
               "Name": "DataSync",
               "Type": "DataSync"
            },
            "value": 14104200
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Similarly I am also getting another JSON response back by calling `urlB` and it is in the exact same JSON format as shown above, but the values for all the keys are different.

Now what I need to do is, I need to serialize JSON response coming from both the URLs (`urlA` and `urlB`) in `DataTransactionMetrics` object only and then iterate `DataTransactionMetrics` object and extract relevant information from it in which I am interested in it. Meaning, I will be extracting few `Name` values from the `DataTransactionMetrics` object in which I am interested in it and populate it into `hostMetricsList` object and at the end print out the full list.

Below is my full code which does the JSON serialization of both the URL's -

```
private static final List<String> hostNames = Arrays.asList("hostA", "hostB", "hostC"); 

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    List<HostMetrics> hostMetricsList = new ArrayList<HostMetrics>();
    for (String hostName : hostNames) {
        Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        Calendar endDate = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
        startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);

        HostMetrics hostMetrics = new HostMetrics(hostName, startDate, endDate);
        hostMetricsList.add(hostMetrics);
    }

    // and then print out the list
    System.out.println(hostMetricsList);
}
```

And below is my `DataTransactionMetrics` class -

```
public class DataTransactionMetrics {

    private String metricName;
    private Map<String, Integer> percentileMap;
    private String median;
    private String stddev;
    private String sumSq;
    private String count;
    private String avg;
    private String max;
    private String min;

    // getters here

    public Dimensions dimensions;

    class Dimensions {
        private String env;
        private String pool;
        @SerializedName("Name")
        private String name;

        // getters here
    }
}
```

And below is my `HostMetrics` class which has all the logic. Can we do some improvements here?

```
public class HostMetrics {

    private String hostName;
    private String totalNumberOfSyncCall;
    private String syncNinetyFivePercentileCall;
    private String syncAvgCall;
    private String syncMaxCall;
    private String totalNumberOfAsyncCall;
    private String asyncNinetyFivePercentileCall;
    private String asyncAvgCall;

    private static final DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    private static RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private static final Gson gson = new Gson();
    private static final Type listOfMetricsType = new TypeToken<List<DataTransactionMetrics>>() {}.getType();
    private static final String BASE_URL = "http://data.host.com/reports/";
    private static final String TRANSACTION_METRIC = "/Transaction?defaultDim=Name&defaultDim=Type&metric=TransactionDuration&percentile=95";
    private static final String EVENT_METRIC = "/Event?defaultDim=Name&defaultDim=Type&metric=TotalCount&percentile=95";

    public HostMetrics(String hostname, Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
        constructURL(hostname, startDate, endDate);
    }

    private void constructURL(String hostname, Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
        String startTime = df.format(startDate.getTime());
        String endTime = df.format(endDate.getTime());

        // construct urlA
        String urlA = BASE_URL + hostName + TRANSACTION_METRIC + "&startTime=" + startTime
                + "&endTime=" + endTime;

        // construct urlB
        String urlB = BASE_URL + hostName + EVENT_METRIC + "&startTime=" + startTime
                + "&endTime=" + endTime;

        // serialize everything in DataTransactionMetrics object, both the URL's
        List<DataTransactionMetrics> dataMetrics = loadMetrics(urlA);
        dataMetrics.addAll(loadMetrics(urlB));

        hostName = hostname;

        for (DataTransactionMetrics metrics : clientMetrics) {
            if (metrics.getDimensions().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("DataSync")) {
                totalNumberOfSyncCall = metrics.getCount();
                syncNinetyFivePercentileCall = String.valueOf(metrics.getPercentileMap().get("95"));
                syncAvgCall = metrics.getAvg();
                syncMaxCall = metrics.getMax();
            } else if (metrics.getDimensions().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("DataASync")) {
                totalNumberOfAsyncCall = metrics.getCount();
                asyncNinetyFivePercentileCall = String.valueOf(metrics.getPercentileMap().get("95"));
                asyncAvgCall = metrics.getAvg();
            }
        }
    }

    private static List<DataTransactionMetrics> loadMetrics(String url) {
        String jsonString = restTemplate.getForObject(url, String.class);

        JsonObject json = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray jarr = json.getAsJsonObject("aggRecords").getAsJsonArray("reportRecords");

        return gson.fromJson(jarr, listOfMetricsType);
    }

    // toString method here
}
```

Now I have got everything working in the above code. I am opting for code review to see whether we can improve anything here in the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `main` method is doing too much. It would be better to extract its content to a method, with a meaningful name.

---

I don't really see the point of this:

> ```
> List<HostMetrics> hostMetricsList = new ArrayList<HostMetrics>();
> for (String hostName : hostNames) {
>     // ...
>     HostMetrics hostMetrics = new HostMetrics(hostName, startDate, endDate);
>     hostMetricsList.add(hostMetrics);
> }
> System.out.println(hostMetricsList);
> ```

Do you really want to print out the `HostMetrics` as a list? Printing them one by one is not good enough?

```
for (String hostName : hostNames) {
    // ...
    HostMetrics hostMetrics = new HostMetrics(hostName, startDate, endDate);
    System.out.println(hostMetrics);
}
```

---

I don't know of a rule against cloning and passing around `Calendar` objects, but it just doesn't seem natural. Instead of this:

> ```
> Calendar startDate = new GregorianCalendar();
> startDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
> Calendar endDate = (Calendar) startDate.clone();
> startDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
> HostMetrics hostMetrics = new HostMetrics(hostName, startDate, endDate);
> ```

I would do like this:

```
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
Date startDate = cal.getTime();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
Date endDate = cal.getTime();

HostMetrics hostMetrics = new HostMetrics(hostName, startDate, endDate);
```

This means of course that you'll have to change the `HostMetrics` constructor to take `Date` params instead of `Calendar`, but I think that's a good thing.

---

Here, appending the `startTime` and `endTime` parameters is duplicated:

> ```
> String urlA = BASE_URL + hostName + TRANSACTION_METRIC + "&startTime=" + startTime
>         + "&endTime=" + endTime;
>
> String urlB = BASE_URL + hostName + EVENT_METRIC + "&startTime=" + startTime
>         + "&endTime=" + endTime;
> ```

I would extract the duplicated parts to a temp variable:

```
String extraParams = "&startTime=" + startTime + "&endTime=" + endTime;
String urlA = BASE_URL + hostName + TRANSACTION_METRIC + extraParams;
String urlB = BASE_URL + hostName + EVENT_METRIC + extraParams;
```

---

Sometimes you call a hostname variable as `hostname`, sometimes `hostName`. One day you might mix them up. I recommend to use `hostname` everywhere consistently.

Answer (score 1):

`java.text.SimpleDateFormat` is [not thread-safe](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#synchronization):

> **Synchronization**
>
> Date formats are not synchronized. It is recommended to create separate format instances for each thread. If multiple threads access a format concurrently, it must be synchronized externally.

Consider using `ThreadLocal<SimpleDateFormat>` instead.  Or, as you are working with Calendar instances, you may find [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) useful in your efforts.

---

The name of `constructURL` is misleading; while it does construct URLs, among other things, it also loads network resources.  Consider splitting the responsibilities:

```
class HostMetricLoader {
  public HostMetrics loadMetrics(String hostname, Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
    final List<DataTransactionMetrics> metrics = new ArrayList<>();
    metrics.addAll(loadMetrics(getUrl(EVENT, hostname, startDate, endDate)));
    metrics.addAll(loadMetrics(getUrl(TRANSACTION, hostname, startDate, endDate)));

    final HostMetrics hostMetrics = new HostMetrics(hostname, startDate, endDate);
    for ( final DataTransactionMetrics data : metrics ) {
      hostMetrics.addData(data);
    }

    return metrics;
  }

  protected String getURL(MetricType type, String hostname, Calendar startDate, Calendar endDate) {
    return String.format(/*...*/);
  }

  protected List<DataTransactionMetrics> loadMetrics(String url) {
    // ...
  }
}

enum MetricType {
  EVENT,
  TRANSACTION;
}

class HostMetrics {
  // fields
  // ...

  public void addData(DataTransactionMetrics data) {
    // if this gets larger, split into two functions
    if (metrics.getDimensions().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("DataSync")) {
      totalNumberOfSyncCall = metrics.getCount();
      syncNinetyFivePercentileCall = String.valueOf(metrics.getPercentileMap().get("95"));
      syncAvgCall = metrics.getAvg();
      syncMaxCall = metrics.getMax();
    } else if (metrics.getDimensions().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("DataASync")) {
      totalNumberOfAsyncCall = metrics.getCount();
      asyncNinetyFivePercentileCall = String.valueOf(metrics.getPercentileMap().get("95"));
      asyncAvgCall = metrics.getAvg();
    }
  }
}
```